# Self Certified SSL for dev machine, but not the URL of the Dev machine

Tags: ssl, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I am wondering if this is at all possible.

I know how to create a self certified SSL on my DEV box

Server > Server Certificate > Create Self Signed Certificate > friendly name

But when i do one one these its for XYZ.mycompainies.com as in its issues to the server.

but i don't want it to be issues to that server name...

on my box i have lets say hello.OddDev.co.uk which is working fine but now i need to test some https stuff on the website, how can i get a self certified SSL for that URL when i have no option to generate one in the GUI

Answer (score 0):

Probably this will help you:
http://corvartech.blogspot.ru/2013/02/generate-self-signed-certificate-on.html
In short IIS certificate creation wizard is easy but doesn't allow for custom CN, and if you need this you may use **SelfSSL.exe**
And if you haven't yet tired of warnings about this in MS documentation keep in mind that self-signed certificates are for development/test purposes only.